# Can I nest CodeIgniter "Helpers" in sub directories?

Tags: codeigniter

I know I can nest libraries in subfolders, but can I do the same for Helpers?

The end result would be to have something to the effect of:

```
application/helpers/foo/bar_helper.php
application/helpers/baz_helper.php
```

Then call the helpers with:

```
$this->load->helper('foo/bar');
$this->load->helper('baz');
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes you can store and load as follows (tested)

```
$this->load->helper('myHelperSubFolder/myHelperName');
```

Even in your `autoload.php` you can load a helper as follows

```
$autoload['helper'] = array('url','myHelpers/functions_helper'); // 'myHelpers' is the folder inside my helper folder and 'functions_helper' is my helper file.
```